# I need help understanding a awk Linux Command

Tags: linux, awk

What does `awk -F: '!($3 < 512 && $4 < 30)' /etc/passwd` do in Linux? I only find awk is a scripting language but cant understand all this is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` world is based on the pattern `condition{action}` and this is applied to every single input record/input line of the input file.

If `{action}` is missing the default action is executed = `print` which actually means `print $0`
if `(condition)` is missing the default condition `true` is used

`-F:` Adjust the field delimiter to be `:` instead of `[[space]]` that is the default field delimiter of awk. Field delimiter in awk can be almost anything , including regex and logical (i.e or) expressions.

`$3` , `$4` The 3rd and 4th field of the input line (delimited by `:` in your code)

`($3 < 512 && $4 < 30)` Is a condition , `&&` is AND operator.

`!` in front of the condition is just a NOT operator, to reverse the logic of the `(condition)`

More interesting options of awk:

`$0`  : is the whole input line read from file, not splitted
`$NF` : is the last field of the input line
`NF`  : is the number of fields
`RS`  : The input record/line separator can be adjusted not to be `\n` (awk's default)
`ORS` : output record separator (default of awk is `\n`)
Try :
`echo "one two three" | awk '{print $2}'`
`echo "one two three" |awk '1' RS=" " ORS="\n"`

And a lot of more info about `awk` can be found either in `man awk`  and `info awk` or in the official awk documentation i.e https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html for `gnu awk - gawk`

Answer (score 0):

This is shorthand for

```
awk -F: '!($3 < 512 && $4 < 30) { print; }' /etc/passwd
```

and means "show all lines where NOT (`:`-separated field #3 is less than 512 and field #4 is less than 30)" from `/etc/passwd`

With the help of `man 5 passwd` and DeMorgan's law, this corresponds to "show the user account list where the user id is greater than 512 or the group id is greater than 30".

This logic is likely intended to only show human users on the system, since a common convention is to assign them higher UIDs than non-human, system users like apache and mysql.

Comment: @thatotherguy `greater than` should be `greater than or equal to` => `user id greater than or equal to 512` OR `group id greater than or equal to 30`